# Add Controllers to <Style> from Code-Behind (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controllers, app.xaml

I'm a beginner in WPF. It's hard as hell just so you know!
ok, i have a little style for my application (Actually i copied it, and really don't know whats happening in the middle so...)
i wanted to add some Hyperlinks and Buttons to header of application. so i edited the style and added those from there.
but now i want to change content of those from code-behind, but as you already know that's not happening!
This is my style in Application.Resources:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="bool2VisibilityConverter" />
            <Color x:Key="WindowBackgroundColor">#FF2D2D30</Color>
            <Color x:Key="HighlightColor">Orange</Color>
            <Color x:Key="BlueColor">AntiqueWhite</Color>
            <Color x:Key="ForegroundColor">#FFF4F4F5</Color>

            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundColor}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource HighlightColor}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource BlueColor}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource ForegroundColor}"/>

            <Style x:Key="WindowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundColorBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightColorBrush}" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BlueColorBrush}" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="{x:Type Hyperlink}" TargetType="Hyperlink">
                <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFF4F4F5"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle" TargetType="local:MainWindow">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundColorBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize" />
                <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
            <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <WindowChrome CornerRadius="0" GlassFrameThickness="1" UseAeroCaptionButtons="False"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MainWindow">
                            <Border x:Name="WindowBorder" Margin="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness}}" Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundColorBrush}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1">
                                        <AdornerDecorator>
                                            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="27" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="7"/>
                                                <Image Width="30" Height="30" />
<!-- This is where i want put those Hyperlinks and the Button -->
                                                <TextBlock Margin="50,5,0,0">
                                                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="SupportPage.xaml" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_Support">Support</Hyperlink>
                                                </TextBlock>
                                                <TextBlock Margin="122,5,0,0">
                                                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="HelpPage.xaml" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_Help">Support</Hyperlink>
                                                </TextBlock>
                                                <Button Name="btCustom" Content="btThatIWantChangeItsContent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                                <TextBlock  Margin="220,5,0,0">
                                                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="AboutPage.xaml" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_About">About</Hyperlink>
                                                </TextBlock>
<!-- to here -->
<Rectangle Mouse.MouseDown="rectangleMoveWindow_MouseDown" Margin="300,0,0,0" x:Name="HeaderBackground" Height="25" Fill="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundColorBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Grid.Row="0">
                                                <Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}}" ToolTip="minimize" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}">
                                                    <Button.Content>
                                                        <Grid Width="30" Height="25" RenderTransform="1,0,0,1,0,1">
                                                            <Path Data="M0,6 L8,6 Z" Width="8" Height="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                        Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" StrokeThickness="2"  />
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </Button.Content>
                                                </Button>
                                                <Grid Margin="1,0,1,0">
                                                    <Button x:Name="Restore" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand}}" ToolTip="restore" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}">
                                                        <Button.Content>
                                                            <Grid Width="30" Height="25" UseLayoutRounding="True" RenderTransform="1,0,0,1,.5,.5">
                                                                <Path Data="M2,0 L8,0 L8,6 M0,3 L6,3 M0,2 L6,2 L6,8 L0,8 Z" Width="8" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                            Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" StrokeThickness="1"  />
                                                            </Grid>
                                                        </Button.Content>
                                                    </Button>
                                                    <Button x:Name="Maximize" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}}" ToolTip="maximize" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}">
                                                        <Button.Content>
                                                            <Grid Width="31" Height="25">
                                                                <Path Data="M0,1 L9,1 L9,8 L0,8 Z" Width="9" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                            Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" StrokeThickness="2"  />
                                                            </Grid>
                                                        </Button.Content>
                                                    </Button>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}}" ToolTip="close"  Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}">
                                                    <Button.Content>
                                                        <Grid Width="30" Height="25" RenderTransform="1,0,0,1,0,1">
                                                            <Path Data="M0,0 L8,7 M8,0 L0,7 Z" Width="8" Height="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                        Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" StrokeThickness="1.5"  />
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </Button.Content>
                                                </Button>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                                                <Path x:Name="ResizeGrip" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="12" Height="12" Margin="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        Stroke="{StaticResource BlueColorBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="None" Data="F1 M1,10 L3,10 M5,10 L7,10 M9,10 L11,10 M2,9 L2,11 M6,9 L6,11 M10,9 L10,11 M5,6 L7,6 M9,6 L11,6 M6,5 L6,7 M10,5 L10,7 M9,2 L11,2 M10,1 L10,3" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </AdornerDecorator>
                                </Border>
                                <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource BlueColorBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="{Binding IsActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Converter={StaticResource bool2VisibilityConverter}}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
                                <Setter TargetName="Maximize" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Restore" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                <Setter TargetName="LayoutRoot" Property="Margin" Value="7" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Normal">
                                <Setter TargetName="Maximize" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Restore" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip" />
                                    <Condition Property="WindowState" Value="Normal" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="ResizeGrip" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

so i don't know how change content of Hyperlinks or even i could replace them with Button if that is necessary. just tell me how i could change those content. of course i have to say i tried FindResource but couldn't find that Hyperlinks or Buttons. Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
<StackPanel x:Name="panel" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="help">Support</sys:String>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Label DataContext="{StaticResource help}">
        <Hyperlink><TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource help}"/></Hyperlink>
    </Label>
    <Button Content="OK" Click="button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    panel.Resources["help"] = "Help";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's great. but not quiet there yet! it works with something like StackPanel and calling itt from that window. but if i want to change something it App.xaml for example, i can not access to it from anywhere! now think of it like something in Application.Resources inside another thing. like a TextBlock inside of a Style inside of Application.Resources! i know...it's crazy! if you could help me, i appreciate it. Thanks again

Comment: xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

Comment: @EISHEN ***xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"*** can add into any *XAML UIElement* section include *Application*

Comment: **<Application.Resources><Style><TextBlock Text="SOMETHING"/></Style></Application.Resources>**

Comment: Thanks a lot. but see that? i want to change the TextBlock Text from some where else. these code that you send, will not find elements inside a Style tag, and that's my problem actually. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this:
1. create a new WpfApplication project
2. ***remove*** ***MainWindow.xaml***
3. add pages: startup.xaml, page1.xaml or more, and set diff background
4. change *StartupUri="startup.xaml"* in *App.xaml*
5. add *NavigationWindow* Style in *App.xaml*

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type NavigationWindow}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type NavigationWindow}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <AdornerDecorator Grid.Row="1">
                            <ContentPresenter Name="PART_NavWinCP" ClipToBounds="true" />
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="20" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label>
                                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="Page1.xaml">Page1</Hyperlink>
                            </Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks man, But i think you get me wrong. this code works just like the one that i paste in first post. now think of it this way: i want to change **NavigateUri** of **Page1** Hyperlink from code-behind or something like this. how can i do that?

Comment: oh...i'm sorry, i deleted my first answer, i think that is what you want.